# Print star pattern using recursive functions in python

Tags: python, recursion

coding fellas I wanna create a ***recursive*** function that would print a star pattern based on the number giving:
It would print the stars times the number giving and go back to line and print the same thing with one less star
then do it again in an ascending way, basically I wanna have this result if I give 4 as a parameter:

```
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
```

here's the code I've written so far it does practically the thing I would except it doesn't print anything after the 1 star is printed it only print blank lines.

```
def etoiles(n):
    print('*'*n)
    etoiles(n-1)

etoiles(4)
```

Comment: don't forget to short circuit the base case *before* making the recursive call! 

e.g. if n == 0: ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a way to stop the recursion and a way to print the other half of the tree. One way is to put the recursion in an `if` statement and just repeat the `print` part.

```
def etoiles(n):
    print('*'*n)
    if n > 1:
        etoiles(n-1)
    print('*'*n)

etoiles(4)
```

Comment: I can't understand why the n is increasing again after the one star is printed ?

Comment: While `n` is greater than one the last print statement is "put on hold" waiting for the recursion to finish. When `n` reaches one it will start printing the last stars in reverse order as the functions return.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions have the notion of a "base case" where they stop recursing. That's what's missing from your `etoiles` function. If `n` is 0, it should stop calling itself.

```
def etoiles(n):
    print('*' * n)
    if n > 0:
        etoiles(n-1)
```

Comment: This is insufficient; it will only print the top half of the pattern.

Comment: It's true, but it's enough to get them moving again~

Comment: (The other minor nit: the base case isn't quite right. If `n` is 0, it will print a blank line.)

Comment: I was asking about the second part bro I've already done the thing that yoou have done read the question before answering

Comment: @wadero "it does practically the thing I would except it doesn't print anything after the 1 star is printed it only print blank lines" I didn't realize that allowing your code to run in an infinite loop was considered "working." Something tells me your instructor wouldn't see it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the other half

```
# Adam's method
def down(n):
    print('*' * n)
    if n > 1:
        down(n-1)

# The reverse of down is up.
def up(s,n):
    print('*' * n)
    if n < s:
        up(s,n+1)

def etoiles(n):
    down(n)
    up(n,1)

etoiles(4)
```

This will output:

```
****
***
**
*
*
**
***
****
```